# Why doesn't the Play button Play in Premiere CS6?

Tags: premiere

I am editing a video in Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 on a 2012 MacBook Pro with the Intel HD Graphics 4000. Sometimes the play button does not play the footage anymore, I can press the button but nothing happens. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

---

***EDIT***

I have figured something out.

Last time I moved my PC, I had to re-plug-in all my stuff. Mic, USB for the external sound hard drive and so on.

Then I started up CS5.5 Premiere Pro and, with all preferences as usual, nothing worked. I pressed the "Play" button and nothing happened.

After a while, I found out that the Default Settings for the Sound in- and output works only but my UX24 Asio driver wasn't accepted anymore in a way that I wasn't able to use the `Play` button.

Well, I closed CS5.5 and then re-re-pluged-in all my Stuff.  Then I opened CS5.5 and selected Asio Ux24 (my soundcard) and everything worked again. Don't ask me why it accepted it this time. Maybe you have to plug in everything in a certain order. Please let me know if that is the case.

My problem now:

I moved my PC again and I face the same problem.  So I did everything I did as described before, but it didn't work.

The last point, and I quote here "Go to Preferences -> Audio Hardware and change Default Device to Built-in Output. Do the same in Preferences -> Audio Output mapping.", was all set. Everything right, as usual. Re-Pluging in the hardware didn't work and re-selecting, restarting didn't work either.

I need support and help, because there are people waiting for me to make videos.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Premiere? Premiere 6 wasn't exactly the most stable thing on the market when it was new, let alone now with all the changes that have happened in hardware and operating systems. Other things to check are to see where your scrub line is on the timeline. If you are at the end or it isn't over a video clip, it might not play anything. Do you see anything in the playback window when you scrub over the video or has the render engine stopped working entirely. Do you have any effects applied that may need to be rendered so that playback can function? We really need more info

Comment: If you meant CS6, which renderer are you using for the project.  (Under Project, Project Settings, General).  Is it the software renderer or the CUDA GPU based one?  If you are using a system with Optimus, it is possible that the NVidia GPU switched off and thus disabled the selected renderer.

Comment: I am working on a MacBook Pro - 2012 with an Intel HD Graphics 4000. The settings are for Mercury Playback Engine - Software only, but it is grayed out so I don't have the option to choose anything else.

Comment: Deleting the audio track from the video then clicking undo (crtl+Z) worked for me :)

Comment: I went to Preferences, Audio Hardware, and then changed Device Class to ASIO. Then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this worked for me:

- Re-Plug-in ALL your External Sound-Hardware.
- Open your Sound Menu from Windows and set your Microphone to your current one. (For me it was the external Soundcard)
- Now Open up Premiere Pro and set everything on your Preferences as previously stated.
  Save your Current Sequenz/Project. Close premiere.
- Reboot your PC.
- Check your Sound Options in Windows, if everything is set right.
  Open Premiere and check again, if your Prefences are still in (everything should be in order)
  Now hit play.
- If the Re-plugin doesnt work, use different USB slots :)

Hope I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you Google this problem, you'll see it's quite common. Below are a few suggestion to fix this problem from a big [Creative Cow thread](http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/931380) about the issue.

- Delete the audio track from the video, hit undo, and see if it plays.
- Create a new sequence and copy paste the old timeline objects in it, see if it plays.
- Right click on the video footage in your source monitor window and then click `Clear in and out`
- Reinstall Premiere Pro CS6
- Go to `Preferences -> Audio Hardware` and change `Default Device` to Built-in Output. Do the same in `Preferences -> Audio Output mapping`.

If one of these fixes work for you, let us know in the comments.

Comment: Create a new sequence worked for me